# Detail UINavigationController issue in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have current `UISplitViewController` setup:

`UISplitViewController` with master `UINavigationController` that contains `UITableViewController` and detail controller that contains `UITabBarController`.

**Code:**

```
    // Create split view controller
    let splitViewController = UISplitViewController()
    let masterViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: UITableViewController())
    masterViewController.topViewController?.title = "Master"

    // Create tab bar controller
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()

    // Setup view controllers
    var viewControllers = [UIViewController]()
    for i in Range(start: 0, end: 4) {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        vc.title = "View Controller \(i+1)"
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        viewControllers.append(navigationController)
    }

    tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers
    splitViewController.viewControllers = [masterViewController, tabBarController]
```

That yields following on iPhone 6S Plus in landscape:

[image: Landscape UISplitViewController]

**Issue:**

After rotation to the portrait mode, `UINavigationController` from detail view controller is replaced with master `UINavigationController`, instead of using navigation controller from the detail view controller.

[image: Split issue]

It's obviously the expected behavior, but I would like to use `UINavigationController` from the detail view controller and still have a back button for the master view controller. You can look at the Facebook Messenger app to see what am I talking about.

Comment: When the `UISplitViewController` collapses, it actually adds the details's navigation controller to the master's navigation controller `viewControllers` stack.  If you examine it, you'll see master VC, detail NC -> detail VC.  What makes you believe the detail navigation controller isn't retained while collapsed?

Comment: Sorry about the misinterpretation. I didn't think of retained as retained in memory, more like used instead of something else. Check the updated question.

Comment: If I recall correctly, it is also used and visible.  If you examine the view hierarchy, the detail navigation controller should appear above the master navigation controller.  What exactly is the problem?  A missing title?

Comment: It seems that under my setup master navigation controller is above the detail navigation controller when device's in portrait mode. This image will help: http://i.imgur.com/soLHKAE.png

Comment: What exact problem are you trying to solve?  A missing detail bar button item while in portrait mode?

Comment: I want to know why master navigation controller is on top of detail navigation controller and can I do the opposite, so that my detail controller is top navigation controller with all customized things such as title, color, bar buttons etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99004/discussion-between-petahchristian-and-said-sikira).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has to do with the fact that you're trying to embed a tab bar controller in a navigation controller, and make that the detail view controller for a split view controller.

The tab bar controller would expect to change navigation items for the selected tab, but your hierarchy is opposite of what it expects.

While the tab bar controller is able to display a selected tab's navigation items on a detail navigation controller which isn't collapsed, things break down once collapsed as the tab bar controller doesn't realize that it's been pushed onto a view controller stack of the master navigation controller.  It's updating the wrong navigation bar at that point.

The SDK doesn't natively support that particular Adaptive UI hierarchy.  You could file a feature request, or see if another developer has code to work around how the split view controller delegate would need to collapse an embedded tab bar controller.